# How to draw a response surface plot for three factorial design?

Tags: r

I have created a three factorial design with two levels (Low & high) using Rstudio. My factors are:

1. Type of catalyst (T-300 coded as -1, TG-300 coded as +1) (Categorical)
2. Loading of TiO2 (0.1 g/L coded as -1, 1.0 g/L coded as +1) (Numerical)
3. Hydrogen peroxide dose (2.5 mL coded as -1, 10 mL coded as +1) (Numerical)

Outcome variable is "`% Degradation of Gallic acid`"

My prediction model is:

```
water <- lm(y ~ C + S + T + C*T + C*S + S*T + C*T*S)
```

or

```
C <- T <- S <- c(-1, +1)

design <- expand.grid(C=C, T=T, S=S)
C <- design$C
T <- design$T
S <- design$S
y <- c(50, 46, 39, 36, 75, 73, 52, 55)
```

My question is how to draw a response surface plot for my model?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please don't use bold. We grok this q is vitally important to you _just fine_ without that "in your face" emphasis. What did you research, then what did you try and what of that did not work. If you researched SO questions and their answers looked like they might work but didn't you should include those links here. If you didn't do that work, you should do that before asking others to write code for you.

Comment: Your question is also about how one can reduce 4-dimensional space to 3-dimensional. That's not a good practice, to use `T` as a variable name. Variable names must be self-explanatory. Moreover, `T` in R is a short-hand for `TRUE` which makes your code ambiguous. The same, I would say about your variable `C`. There is function `c` in R. And when I read your code, seeing `C` makes me think about `c()` at first, so I think it's not good practice as well.  The last, but not least - providing the example data set, will help other people to answer your question, so please `dput()` some data for us

Answer (score 1):

You can draw a 3D contour plot of the response surface using the `misc3d` package.  This needs a function that gives predictions from your fitted model.

It also needs you to choose a grid of values for C, T, and S that covers the range of interest.  I'd suggest about 10 levels for each.

You need to choose contour levels to plot.  Your data lie between 36 and 73, so maybe values like 40, 50, 60, 70 would be interesting.  Use `heat.colors(4)` or some other palette for these.

The `contour3d` function doesn't normally show axes; you'll want to add those.

Putting this all into code:

```
pred <- function(C, T, S) predict(water, newdata = data.frame(C, T, S))

C1 <- T1 <- S1 <- seq(-1, 1, len = 10)

library(rgl)
library(misc3d)
contour3d(pred, x=C1, y=T1, z=S1, level=c(40, 50, 60, 70), color = heat.colors(4))
decorate3d(xlab = "C", ylab = "T", zlab = "S")
```

This produces this plot (which I've rotated a little to make things more visible):

[image]

The red surface is the response of 40, the light yellow is 70.  You can see that the level of C doesn't matter much; you get the highest response at low T and high S.